# ¿Cómo crear una cuenta regresiva con PHP?

Tags: php

Llevo alrededor de una semana buscando una manera de crear una cuenta regresiva teniendo como referencia la cantidad de segundos que faltan. Todavía no logro encontrar una solución que realmente me funcione acorde a mi caso que es distinto a los que hay en Stackoverflow. He intentado códigos en múltiples fuentes una de ellas W3Schools y no logro crear la cuenta regresiva correctamente.

Mi código actualmente es:

```
$seconds = (int) ($restart / 20);
$minutes = (int) ($restart / 1200);
$hours = (int) ($restart / 72000);
echo $seconds . ":" . $minutes . ":" . $hours;
```

Donde `$restart` es la cantidad de segundos que faltan para que ocurra un evento X. El código anterior da el siguiente resultado teniendo la variable `$restart` un valor asignado de `3660` segundos:

```
0:61:1
```

El resultado esperado es el siguiente:

```
0:1:1
```

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: A mi tu codigo me despliega `183:3:0`

Comment: hola soy el mismo que publicó la pregunta solo que soy invitado por tanto no puedo comentar y se cerró la sesión al refrescar la página, intenté el código que me diste y no funcionó me marca minutos en vez de segundos y no funciona.

Comment: A que te refieres? Dame ejemplos.

Comment: Dark Matter, como sigas posteando comentarios, va a acabar bloqueándose tu cuenta. Deja que mire las dos cuentas y las uno. Por favor espera un poco.

Answer (score 2):

Para lograr el resultado que quieres, tienes que utilizar el operador mod `%` que es el residuo de la división.  Algo así:

```
<?php
$restart = 3660;
$seconds = (int) ($restart % 3600) % 60;
$minutes = (int) ($restart % 3600) / 60;
$hours = (int) ($restart / 3600);
echo $seconds . ":" . $minutes . ":" . $hours;

?>
```

versión online:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f32316da6fde3977687a919c2a912b4f68144008

Comment: El OP comenta: "intenté el código que me diste y no funcionó me marca minutos en vez de segundos y no funciona".